# WCF: in async contract I return List<T> but I receive in client an array

Tags: arrays, wcf, list, asynchronous

In my WCF service contract I have declared an asyn method that return a List, but when in my client I receive the return from the method, I receive an array. My contract is the following:

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
IAsyncResult BeginGetUsers(Paramusers paramUserParameters, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
List<Users> EndGetUsers(IAsyncResult result);
```

In my client I have the following code:

```
Task<List<Users>> task = Task<List<Users>>.Factory.FromAsync(_proxy.Proxy.BeginGetUsers, _proxy.Proxy.EndGetUsers, myParameters,  null);
List<Users> myUsers = await task;
```

In the client, I receive an error in the second parameter of FromAsync method, because it says that the EndGetUsers method returns an array, not a list.

I try to use an array of users and works fine, but I would like to receive the list from the async method, not an array. is it possible?

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create your client proxy, specify that you want collections to be represented as lists instead of arrays - when using the "Add Service Reference" dialog, choose the "Advanced" button, then select `System.Collections.Generic.List` in the collection type drop-down list.

If you use `svcutil`, you can use the `/collectionType` (or `/ct`) parameter to specify the type of collections to use:

```
svcutil http://the.service.com/service.svc /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

Comment: Well, I create the proxy with the svcutils, not with the VS GUI. When I try to add a service reference, I can't find any service, so I always use svcUtils to create my Service.cs and then use this class to create my proxy in the client. is it possible to use your solution with svcutils?  Thanks.

Comment: One quiestion more. I only select a type of list or I can use many of them? For example, if for some methods I want to return a list and for other return an oversableCollection, for example.

Comment: With svcutil you can use the /ct option (updated the answer with that). And the setting is global, you can't have one operation with one collection type and another with other. You can, however, edit the generated proxy to change from `T[]` to `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`, they're equivalent as far as WCF is concerned.