# WCF : Data type returned by API geting altered on client side

Tags: c#, wcf

I have written a web service with the following Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInsightsPortalServices
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<MetadataItem> GetDataSources(Context context);
}
```

When I host the service and write a client program to consume it, I see that the return type of the method on the client side is an array (MetadataItem[]). I had expected to get a list (List) as returned from the service.

What explains such a behavior? In what other ways would the returned object be altered?

Is there anything I should know and be cautious about while sending my own object as result of a WCF service call?

Comment: Are you using "Add service reference" to generate the client?

Comment: I think you can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401271/wcf-in-async-contract-i-return-listt-but-i-receive-in-client-an-array.